# How is length contraction reconciled with other objects occupying space?

Tags: special-relativity

Say I have a ball at 0.999999% the speed of light going past the Sun toward Earth. Now from the ball's reference frame, the distance between Earth and Sun is the same length as the ball's diameter. Why is the ball occupying the entire space between the Earth and Sun? What happened if a comet was between the Earth and Sun in the ball's path? Would the comet be inside the ball?!

Comment: The ball does not magically "occupy" in one go. If there is a comet there it gets hit just like a automobile would hit something in the road as it moves along. There is no mystery there.

Comment: 0.999999% of the speed of light isn't that much. Length of contraction isn't going to noticeable.

Comment: @StanLiou I bet he meant 99.999999% instead of  0.999999%! Otherwise it really doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @gonenc yuh; I was just obliquely pointing that out. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the barn paradox! It's about the same thing.

The problem is that there's an extra effect in relativity you haven't accounted for: observers don't agree on the order of events. For example, in the earth frame, we may have the ordering

1. Back of ball at sun
2. Something passes between sun and Earth
3. Front of ball at Earth

In the ball's frame of reference, 1 and 3 happen at the same time. So it appears to mean that 2, which is between 1 and 3, must also happen at that time. But there's actually no such guarantee! The ordering may be

2'. Something passes between earth and sun

1'/3'. Ball occupies space between earth and sun

which resolves the paradox.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the question slightly and instead of the ball consider a spherical region of space, then your spherical region of space would indeed include the Earth, the Sun and and everything in between such as Venus, comets, asteroids etc.

Well, not quite. Remember that the contraction is only in the direction of motion so the Earth, Sun etc are flattened into disks from your point of view. Your spherical region of space only includes the centres of the disks and it wouldn't include any other celestial bodies unless they lay within one ball radius of the line the ball is moving along. The probability of this is astronomically (pun intended) low.

If you swap the *ball shaped region of space* for a real ball you get a huge explosion as soon as your ball hits the first thing in its path.

Comment: What about the space that the ball occupies? The fairly large one... I mean from the ball's perspective it has a length of 1 meter just like the distance between Earth and Sun...

Comment: Yes, the ball occupies a large volume of the other frame, but it's a solid ball. You can't have things inside it. Assuming the ball starts out in space as it nears the Solar System it doesn't *engulf* the Earth. It would just hit it and explode. Interestingly, the Earth dwellers would see the length of the ball **decreased** i.e. the ball volume would decrease. You're going to have to reach for your [Lorentz transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation) to see why ...

Comment: @JohnRennie "so the Earth, Sun etc are flattened into disks from your point of view." That depends on the direction in which they move: an approaching sphere appears flattened, a receding sphere appears elongated, and a passing sphere appears rotated. See [Terrell rotation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrell_rotation).

Comment: How can the same ball be near the Sun and not near the Sun at the same time?

Comment: Like be burned by the sun and at the same time being cooled by Earth's atmosphere from Earth's point of view?

Comment: @BinaryBurst *simultaneity is relative*. From the ball's point of view, it passes the earth and the sun at the same time. But for a stationary observer, the ball passes the sun and the earth at two different moments in time.

Comment: And if lenght contraction happens.. With respect to what part of the ball does the contraction happen? :)

Comment: @Pulsar: an approaching sphere will *look* spherical i.e. that's what would be on the image if you photographed it. However if you measured the time interval between the leading and trailing edges passing you and divided by the speed you would find the ball had indeed contracted.

Comment: @BinaryBurst: you are making the common misstep of applying intuition to relativity. To understand what is going on you need to do the sums. Search the site for *lorentz contraction* for many questions exploring this area.

Comment: @BinaryBurst *"How can the same ball be near the Sun and not near the Sun at the same time?"* Note that you have used the phrase *"at the same time"*. This phrase assumes that there is an absolute meaning to simultaneity of spatially separated events (which seems intuitively obvious), but the observed facts of the universe contradict this assumption. That phrase *has no meaning* when applied to things that are "space-like separated".

Comment: Ok, I think I didn't state my question well enough. From the ball's perspective the ball is burned by the sun because it's close to it. So the ball is in flames and blows and is ripped apart etc... From Earth's perspective the ball is flattened to a disk and is frozen because it is in empty space where the temperature is -60 degrees C. Why can the ball have two entirely different fates just because you switch reference frames? :)

Comment: @BinaryBurst You have presumed a trajectory that passes near both the Earth and the Sun. From *all* observers point of view the final fate is the same, the only thing that changes is *when* that fate is encountered, and that is relative (i.e. there is no absolute when).

Answer (score 0):

This sort of effort at constructing a paradox usually gets answered by correctly defining the frames of reference and also considering the relativity of simultaneity. It's not just length contraction or expansion that is needed for proper resolution but also consideration of what it means to say "at the same time". I don't think you have defined the various viewpoints fully. From the Earth frame, the "ball" would really appear to be a disc and there would be plenty of space to avoid the ball, From the ball's frame, the comet would either be passing through the region of space before or after the ball was "there".